# Question about generating functions with trig

Tags: generating-functions

Consider there recurrence relation
$$a_n=\frac{5}{4} a_{n-1} \cos{(\pi\cdot a_{n-1})}.$$

I am trying to find the generating function $A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n.$

I've tried the following:

$$a_n=\frac{5}{4} a_{n-1} \cos{(\pi\cdot a_{n-1})}\\ 
\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n = \frac{5}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}\cos{(\pi \cdot a_{n-1})}x^n \\
\implies A(x)-a_0 = \frac{5}{4}x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \cos{(\pi \cdot a_n)} x^n.$$

This is just where I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your initial value?  (the value of $a_1$)

Comment: $\frac{5}{4}x\cos(\pi x)$ doesn't seem like a nice function to iterate. Is there any reason to believe this will generally have a closed-form solution?

Comment: @Goos Say $a_0=1$

Comment: @anon not necessarily, just hopeful that it does